# Dart DateTime.parse removing 1 hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, dart, flutter

I'm currently developing a flutter application with a node.js server. When the time stored in the database is parsed, it returns a an hour less than when it is parsed to a javascript date object.

**Example:**

**Javascript:**

```
var date = new Date(); // Current Time 5:19 pm

console.log(date.toISOString()); // Returns 2019-04-03T16:19:26.578Z
console.log(date.getHours()); // Returns 17 (correct)
```

Let's assume the `2019-04-03T16:19:26.578Z` returned is stored on the database. On my flutter/dart application, here's what happens:

**Dart:**

```
void main() {  
  DateTime date = DateTime.parse("2019-04-03T16:19:26.578Z");   
  print(date.hour); // returns 16 (incorrect)
}
```

Please how do I reconcile this time difference to make the time correct on both javascript and dart?

NOTE: This discrepancy only occurs with parsed ISO times. running `Date().getHours()` and `DateTime.now().hour` give the same answer

Comment: You probably want [DateTime.toLocal()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/DateTime/toLocal.html) since the parsed datetime represents UTC

Comment: Daylight savings?

Comment: $phuzi - that's not my question. I'm talking about the hour returned in both cases